# Pandas column extracting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of *movies* and given a *column* name **actors**. I want to create a new dataframe say **Johnny Depp** having his movies in this dataframe from the dateset *movies*. 
Also there is a genre column having elements as **Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi
**. I want to extract the first two words from it i.e *Action, Adventure* and store them in two separate column.

```
words = movies.genres.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('|').str[1])
```

this the code i have written for genre but getting error as 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: How is the actors column formatted? Is there only a single actor in a column, or are there multiple actors separated by a separator?

Comment: multiple actors in the column actor

Comment: can you share a sample data

Comment: genre:[Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi, Action|Adventure|Fantasy]
actor_1_name:[CCH Pounder, Johnny Depp]

Comment: Have you NaNs in your dataframe? Try to drop these with `df.dropna(inplace=True)` then use your code. Also: Do you have rows that only contain one genre? This wouldn't work with `.str[1]`.

Comment: NaNs are already dropped and yes it contain one genre for some. Then what should be rectified?

Comment: There are almost two questions here. First how to split the genres into a workable format, and second how to slice the Data to pull a specific actor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
ll = [['Johnny Depp', 'a|b|c', 'Movie_1'],['Johnny Depp', 'a|d', 'Movie_2'],['Marlon Brando', 'f', 'Movie_3']]
movies = pd.DataFrame(ll,columns=['actors','genres','titles'])
print(movies)

# Get it as matrix of 0,1.
genre_df = movies.genres.str.get_dummies()
print(genre_df)

# Bonus: get a column containing list of first 2 genres.
genre_df['first_genre'] = pd.Series([''.join(genre_df.iloc[i,:][genre_df.iloc[i,:] == 1][0:1].index.tolist()) for i in range(len(genre_df))])
genre_df['second_genre'] = pd.Series([''.join(genre_df.iloc[i,:][genre_df.iloc[i,:] == 1][1:2].index.tolist()) for i in range(len(genre_df))])
genre_df['actors'] = movies['actors']
genre_df['titles'] = movies['titles']
print(genre_df)

# Get Depp movie info only.
depp_df = genre_df[genre_df['actors'] == 'Johnny Depp'][['first_genre', 'second_genre', 'titles']]
print(depp_df)
```

Hopefully this is in the format you want, I couldn't quite understand.

Comment: its working but the format I was talking about 
first genre:[a]
second genre: [b]

Comment: Edited 2s to 1s. In your question you have `str[1]` but mention first `first two words`. A minimal sample would be great.

Comment: Edited for multi column format. They're strings now, but if you prefer single-element lists you can just remove the `''.join()` call.

Comment: **genre:**[Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi, Action|Adventure|Fantasy] **actor_1_name:**[CCH Pounder, Johnny Depp].
This is what the sample looks like